# TCP session is not timing out even when link is shut

Tags: tcp-ip

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

Sequence of steps:

1. Using `nc -l 9999` started listening on Ubuntu VM.
2. Ran nc client is on another Linux VM to connect to the above server
3. The interface connecting the client to the server is shut down.

The client application is not going down even after a long time (a few hours).

There is no alternate connection to the server, as it's an interface address which was shut. Also tcpdump doesn't show any traffic.

I also tried changing different tcp parameters using sysctl -w <>  but no impactwas seen and all connections remain

Is this expected? I am using `nc` to replicate an issue wherein portscanner is connecting to an application (service port) and disconnecting ungracefully. The server keeps all these connections alive forever. Is this expected? Why doesn't `tcp keepalive` kick in to cleanup?

It is seen across all tcp applications including Cassandra/ZooKeeper and in house applications.

Comment: You can lower up keepalive sysctl values.http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html . Also would be interesting to see at which state your connection remains, f.e. using  `netstat -tlpena | grep nc` . There are also couple sysctls to reduce/increase timeouts of TCP flags.

Comment: Thaks@fugitive! I tried changing several knobs to no avail. I will update the description